# Help proving inequality by induction with recurrent sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

**Problem**

For a sequence, $u_n$ , $u_1=u_2=1$ and  $u_{n+2}=u_{n+1}+u_n$

Using induction, prove $u_n<2^n$

So, I'm having trouble working through this. I've tried coming up with a conjecture for $u_n$ but it doesn't seem to work:
$u_1=1$, $u_2=1$, $u_3=2$, $u_4=3$, $u_5=5$

I don't see a pattern. I'm assuming this isn't the way to go about this problem.

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to do anything clever here, you can just directly apply induction. You already know the statement is true for $n=1,2$. Now assume the statement is true for $n$ and $n+1$. Show that it follows that the statement is true for $n+2$.

Comment: Just do the induction, since the statement is given to you.

Answer (score 0):

Because the base is obvious and by the assumption of the induction we obtain:$$u_{n+2}<2^n+2^{n-1}=3\cdot2^{n-1}<4\cdot2^{n-1}=2^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Technically, would you say this argument is strong induction?

Comment: @Moed Pol Bollo We can say so.

Comment: How did you obtain the LHS of the second inequality? @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @natojato $2^n+2^{n-1}=2\cdot2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}=(2+1)2^{n-1}=3\cdot2^{n-1}.$

Answer (score 0):

For this (strong) induction, you first need to prove the base cases when $n=1$ and 2.  Thus you need to show that $u_1< 2^1$.  Since $u_1$ is 1 and $2^1$ is 2 the $n=1$ case is true.  Similarly, $u_2=1<2^2=4$.

Now for the induction step, suppose that 
$$
(*)\quad u_n < 2^n
$$
for all values of $n$ less than say $k$ which is greater than 2.  Can you then prove that $u_k < 2^k$?  We know that 
$$
u_k = u_{k-2}+u_{k-1} .
$$
The idea is to apply (*) twice to the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

**The Base of induction**
\begin{align}
a_1 &= 1<2^1  \\
a_2 &= 1<2^2
\end{align}

**Induction from $n$ to $n+1$**

\begin{align}
a_n &< 2^n  \\
a_{n+1} &< 2^{n+1}  \\
\implies a_{n+2} &= a_n+a_{n+1}  \\
&< 2^{n}+2^{n+1}  \\
&< 2^{n+1}+2^{n+1}  \\
&= 2^{n+2}
\end{align}
and the proof is complete.